# Error when instantiating a form with arguments

Tags: c#, forms

This loads the correct form

```
private void loadResults()
    {
        Results userResultsForm = new Results();
        userResultsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

However this loads a blank form

```
private void loadResults()
    {
        Results userResultsForm = new Results(correctAnswers);
        userResultsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

This the code in Results

```
public Results()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Results(bool[] correctAnswers)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.correctAnswers = correctAnswers;
    }
```

InitializeComponent is called first

Comment: If you right click the `Results(correctAnswers)` and chose `Go To Definition`, what's in that constructor? Does that constructor call `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: When I do this I get an error message saying "cannot navigate to definaition"

Comment: I'm not sure, but seeing the code you editted the problem is that your second constructor does not, in fact, call `InitializeComponent();`. Add that as the first line in your second constructor and it will fix your problem, or have it call `: this()` like Luaan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `Results` constructor is wrong, and doesn't call the `InitializeComponent` method.

The usual pattern for alternate constructors for a form would be something like this:

```
public Results()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public Result(Answer[] answers) : this()
{
  // Do whatever you need with the answers
}
```

This makes sure that the "basic" constructor runs before yours, initializing the form properly.